# Why yup is trigger my tests even though previous tests are failing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yup

I want to validate my object with the schema using yup.

But I notice that when I wrote my own test function it's trigger anyway.

I mean I validate the `age` property for number, null, positive, integer value. then I want to continue with my own logic test.

So I expect to NOT enter the function unless the previous tests are valid.

I'm not sure if this is how it meant to be, but in this way I must also check for valid input in my tests function, even though I add the number, null, positive, integer checks.

So am I using the yup wrong?

What I expect form yup is not invoke the test if the previous tests are invalid.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-p8rdm4)

```
import { object, string, number, date, InferType } from 'yup';

let userSchema = object({
  age: number()
    .nullable()
    .positive()
    .integer()
    .test({
      message: 'test message',
      test: (v) => {
        console.log('in test!', v);
        return !!v.toPrecision();
      },
    }),
});

userSchema
  .validate({ age: null })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log({ res });
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log({ e });
  });
```

Comment: You marked `null` as valid input when you added `.nullable()`. So `{ age: null }` might not be the best data to test this since it's valid. If you where to pass `{ age: "foobar" }` you'll see that the `console.log()` will not run, because `"foobar"` is not `null` and also not a positive integer.

Comment: so for every test I must check if it's null?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with yum, there might be helpers in the library. If the test is just what you have above `v => v === null || !!v.toPrecision()` is not that complex. Alternatively you could also write your own helper. `const unlessNull = (fnTest) => (value, context) => value === null || fnTest(value, context)`, which allows you to define the test function like so `unlessNull(v => !!v.toPrecision())`